# Queryset objetos duplicados sin perder cantidad en Django Python

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hola estoy haciendo una consulta y no logro dar con el resultado esperado.

este es mi modelo:

```
class EntregaItem(models.Model):
   entrega = models.ForeignKey(Entrega, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
   item = models.ForeignKey('equipos.Equipos', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
   codigo = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='-')
   cantidad = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

al hacer esta consulta:

```
item_entrega = EntregaItem.objects.filter(entrega__servicio=request.POST['id'])
```

obtengo elementos duplicados:

[image: items duplicados]

y me gustaría obtener elementos únicos pero sumar su cantidad, no solo excluirlos:

[image: cantidad sumada]

Espero me puedan ayudar, saludos.

Comment: `EntregaItem.objects.filter(entrega__servicio=request.POST['id']).annotate(num_codigos=Count('codigo'))`???

Comment: @JackNavaRow creo que lo que quiere es un `Sum` de las cantidades

Comment: Gracias..!! @JackNavaRow lo probaré, pero si necesito sumar las cantidad.

Comment: [Mira la guia de Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards), espero que te ayude.

Comment: @JackNavaRow lo revisaré. Gracias.

Comment: En realidad ya lo había leído para hacer el filtro, lo volví a leer, probar y no logro dar con el resultado. :-/. 
Tambien probé consulta que pones @JackNavaRow y no funciona.

Comment: EntregaItem.objects.values('item_id').order_by('item_id').distinct()
Obtengo una lista de items sin items repetidos, pero pierdo la cantidad de los objetos que son excluidos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente pude hacer el Queryset de esta forma. Así me sumó el campo cantidad y devuelve elementos(items) únicos.

```
item_entrega = EntregaItem.objects.values('codigo').order_by('codigo').annotate(suma=Sum('cantidad'))
```

Me devuelve esto:
<QuerySet [{'codigo': 'A-100', 'suma': 1}, {'codigo': 'A-60', 'suma': 2}]>

al utilizar values_list(), me devuelve esto:
<QuerySet [('A-100', 1), ('A-60', 2)]>

Gracias.